# How to handle SOAP response in FLEX 3

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, soap, response

---

SOAP Request

---

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   
 <S:Header/>
   
 <S:Body>
       
 <ns2:deleteDataView xmlns:ns2="http://ws.$$$$$.@@@@@.####.com/">
            
<identifier>5</identifier>
        </ns2:deleteDataView>

```
&lt;/S:Body&gt;
```

</S:Envelope>

---

SOAP Response

---

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>     <S:Body>
>        
>  <ns2:deleteDataViewResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.$$$$$.@@@@@.####.com/">
>            
>  <return>ERROR: A bug has been encountered,please try later</return&gt
>
>  </ns2:deleteDataViewResponse>
>     </S:Body>
> </S:Envelope>

---

I want to read SOAP response in flex,**am some what** ***new*** to FLEX,pls help,even good resources will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Handling SOAP Response**

```
<mx:WebService
      id="userRequest"
       wsdl="http://www.gnpcb.org/esv/share/soap/index.php?wsdl">

       <mx:operation name="doPassageQuery" resultFormat="object"
            fault="mx.controls.Alert.show(event.fault.faultString)"
            result="showResult(event)"/>
 </mx:WebService>
```

In the above code you are accessing your SOAP WebService, now you have the resultFormat is an **`Object`** and the result function is showResult()

```
  private function showResult(e:ResultEvent):void 
   {
   trace(e.result);
   }
```

**Resources**

http://www.flexlive.net/?p=79